# Hybris - B2C and B2B as different modules in the same project

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to have 2 accelerators, B2C and B2B, in the same project, both working like a separate module with different webroot. Is that possible ?

I have already working B2C accelerator with custom extensions in one module. What I'm trying to achieve is to create another module (used for B2B) that will have same capabilities to use custom extensions and have different storefront on different URL. I tried creating new customized B2B accelerator following this [SAP tutorial](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/1811/en-US/8acc8a5a86691014a20781b3f738213e.html) and I got the correct structure of extensions generated, but then I got some error when using 
`ant clean all`, with duplicate attributes for fulfilmentprocess extension.

I tried to use b2b_acc recipe as well, but there it failed during `ant modulegen` and the structure was not correctly generated.

What are my options here, is it possible to have 2 different modules for B2C and B2B, or I can have only B2B addon for B2C ? How to handle different storefronts on different URLs and some specific overrides for B2C and B2B ? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754530/in-hybris-how-to-create-b2b-and-b2c-storefronts-in-the-same-code-base/46790376#46790376

Comment: @Michal Which Hybris version are you using?

Comment: JohannesNolte, it is a duplicate, but I didn't find a working solution in that post. I described what I tried, so also creating another module, B2B and got errors when building. I could make some mistake, or it can depend on current configuration, but I need more specific, step by step tutorial how to proceed. @HybrisHelp currenlty we are on build 1811.7

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to have 2 different modules for B2C and B2B?

Yes, you can have B2B & B2C running together. Use Hybris recipe to add that flavor to your site.

> How to handle different storefronts on different URLs and some
>   specific overrides for B2C and B2B?

Generate another storefront using **extgen** and install B2B addons on it. You can maintain different URLs by setting the differnt webroot context.

---

1) Install the recipe `b2c_b2b_acc` or which has both B2C & B2B. This helps you to configure the **localextensions.xml** with the require the extensions.

2) Run the modulegen with `accelerator` template to generate a custom module. Here you will have a custom storefront extension which you can treat for B2C changes

3) Configure the generated custom storefront extension (Let's say B2CStorefront) as a template. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736566/2478134) for the details steps.

4) Generate another storefront extension by using **extgen**. You can see your custom storefront extension in the template options, choose it and you will have another clone storefront extension. Let me say B2BStorefront.

5) Now install B2B addons as per your requirements. Like b2bacceleratoraddon, commerceorgaddon.

6) Configure website & media URL in both storefront extensions as per your requirements

7) Build & Initialize the system

Comment: Thanks for detailed advice. Actually I've tried this approach yesterday, I just started from point 3, because B2C accelerator was already implemented. It is working fine, at least storefront changes that I tried. This approach is probably recommended, but I was wondering, if there is a possibility to have different module for B2B, so whether we can override also other extensions (core, facades...) so we don't affect B2C accelerator when we are developing B2B. Because now we would have to edit existing classes (besides storefront) in B2C, to achieve some customization, am I correct?